# Does $f'(x_*)=0\Rightarrow |e_{n+1}|<C|e_n|^2$ in the fixed-point iteration method?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

(Multiple options could be correct!)

> **Q.** Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a twice continuously differentiable function with a unique fixed-point $f(x_*)=x_*$. For a given $x_0\in [0,1],$ consider the iteration $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ for $n\ge 0.$ If
> $L=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|$, then which of the following are true?
>
> (a) If $L< 1,$ then $(x_n)$ converges to $x_*.$
>
> (b) $(x_n)$ converges to $x_*$ provided $L\ge 1.$
>
> (c) The error $e_n=x_n-x_*$ satisfies $|e_{n+1}|<L|e_n|.$
>
> (d) If $f'(x_*)=0,$ then $|e_{n+1}|<C|e_n|^2$ for some $C>0.$

**My attempt:**

I know that when a numerical equation $\phi(x)=0$  is expressed as $f(x)=x,$ the real roots can be found by the process of fixed-point iteration. Furthermore, the condition of convergence requires that $L$ (as written in the question!) be less than $1$ throughout the interval $(x_0,x_*).$ So, option (a) is correct. This implies option (b) is false. In addition, we have:
$$f(x_{i-1})-f(x_*)=x_i-x_*,\,i=1,2,\ldots,n,(n+1),\ldots.$$

Also, LMVT gives us:
$$f(x_i)-f(x_*)=(x_i-x_*)f'(\xi_i),\,x_i\le \xi_i \le x_*,\,i= 0,1,\ldots,n,(n+1),\ldots.$$

Therefore,
$$x_i-x_*=(x_{i-1}-x_*)f'(\xi_{i-1}),\,i=1,2,\ldots,n,(n+1),\ldots.$$

That is,
$$e_i=e_{i-1}f'(\xi_{i-1}),\,i=1,2,\ldots,n,(n+1),\ldots.\tag1$$

For $i=n+1,$ Eq. $(1)$ becomes:
$$e_{n+1}=e_n f'(\xi_{i-1})\\
\Rightarrow |e_{n+1}|=|e_n|\cdot|f'(\xi_{i-1})|\le L|e_n|.$$

This suggests that option (c) is correct. Am I right? If yes, is there an easier way to confirm this?

Now, $f'(x_*)=0\Rightarrow x_i=x_*,$ or $e_i=0,$ according to Eq. $(1).$ On the surface, option (d) appears false. But, I am not sure! Please give some insights...

EDIT. Changed the title, modified the tags, and fixed some typos.

Comment: The conclusion (d) ,with $\le ,$ is correct provided the function $f$ is twice continuously differentiable.  Part (b) is false: $f(x)=1-x,$ $x_0=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Sir, I am failing to see how option (d) is correct. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Please avoid "Sir". Just Ryszard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume  $f''$ is continuous (or bounded) on $[0,1].$ By the Taylor formula for $n=2$ we get
$$f(x)=f(x^*)+f'(x^*)(x-x^*)+{1\over 2}f''(\xi)(x-x^*)^2$$ for a point $\xi$ between $x^*$ and $x.$
If $f'(x^*)=0$ the middle term vanishes and we get
$$|f(x)-x^*|=|f(x)-f(x^*)|\le M(x-x^*)^2,\qquad M={1\over 2}\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|f''(t)|$$
Thus
$$|e_{n+1}|=|x_{n+1}-x^*|=|f(x_{n})-x^*|\le M(x_n-x^*)^2=Me_n^2$$
**Remark** I consider the strict inequalities in $(c)$ and $(d)$ misprints. Let
$f(x)=0$ for all $0\le x\le 1.$
The point $x^*=0$ is the only fixed point. For any $x_0$ we get $x_n=0$ for  $n\ge 1.$ Thus $e_n=0$ for $n\ge 1,$ and we cannot have strict inequalities in (c) and (d).

Comment: Given that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable in its domain, I believe we can just assume $f$ is bounded on $[0,1].$ Thanks...

Comment: You welcome. The proof requires the boundedness of $f''.$ So continuity of $f''$ is not essential.

Comment: I made a typo! Wanted to write $f''$ is bounded on $[0,1].$

Comment: One last thing: I noticed option (c), with $\le$, is correct. However, $<$ is given in the question. The same goes for option (d) as well. Considering that $<$ is a stronger condition than $\le$, shall we mark options (c) & (d) correct or not?

Comment: I have added a remark concerning $<.$

Comment: @JeffreyHarkness The point is that $C$ should be independent of $n.$

Comment: @Ryszard, I of course agree.  Perhaps I should have written something more like $C \ge sup\ _{0 \le n \le \infty}  \ 2 \frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^2}$ works, since by the Taylor series expansion you show, for any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_n)| = 2\frac{|f(x_n) - f(x_*)|}{|x_n - x_*|^2} = 2\frac{|x_{n+1} - x_*|}{|x_n - x_*|^2} = 2\frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^2}$?  This appears essentially to be the same conclusion.